# Mail not sent in post action in PHP, it Showing the following error

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

the following line showing error while we sent mail in post action from HTMl

```
13   $headers = "From:" . $from;
 14   $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
 15   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 16   mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);
```

This is the error showing during the submit button click,

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550  No such
>   user here in D:\InetPub\vhosts\aaa.com\httpdocs\mail_handler.php on
>   line 15
>
> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550  No such
>   user here in D:\InetPub\vhosts\aaa.com\httpdocs\mail_handler.php on
>   line 16 Mail Sent. Thank you aaa, we will contact you shortly.

**am using Hostgator Control Pannel

Comment: give more details

Comment: u mean the full code.. , or what i mean. , it means that the two line showing the error in the php page ,

Comment: My guess would be that the STMP server only allow you to send mail when the from user is defined, and known. So, what's in `$headers` and what are the rules of the SMTP server you're using?

Comment: i had modified my code, what the headers include, i had given both From and to address, "what are the rules of the SMTP server you're using?"- this i didnt understand.

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779165/sending-mail-to-local-mail-server-sent-550-the-address-is-not-valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, it may work

```
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);
```